# gtk2hs - converting Color to a hex triplet

Tags: haskell, gtk, rgb, gtk2hs, color-depth

I'm working in Haskell with gtk2hs, and have come across a problem I can't find an answer to.

I am writing a very simple program: it takes a colour value (or multiple colour values), and then will apply a function to them.  It can do things like complementary colours, the mean of a set of colours, and so on. I've finished putting the interface together in Glade, and have read a few simple tutorials on using gtk2hs; everything works so far, and my interface will show up when I run my program.

However, my problem is with the `ColorSelection` widget. When I get my value from it, the value it gives is of the type `Color Word16 Word16 Word16`, where each `Word16` is between 0 and 65535. What I want to be able to do is to convert that into a Hex triplet (as a `String`) ideally, or something that I can convert into a Hex triplet. So far, I've found out that it seems to be something to do with the fact that colours are stored as rrrrggggbbbb, rather than the HTML-style rrggbb. What I've found, using this code:

```
colorToHex (Color a b c)
    =  (showHex a "") ++ " " ++ (showHex b "") ++ " " ++ (showHex c "")
```

is that, although most of the time it's accurate, when using the colour picker tool I can input a colour that seems different to what is output. For example, using the colour picker, I selected `#A9D06E` - however, my function returned `"aa11 d12d 6e41"`. Although fairly close, I can't work out the relationship - how does the rounding for the red channel work in this example? Also, if I type the hex value `#A9D06E` directly, I get `"a9a9 d0d0 6e6e"`.

I have tried using Hoogle to find a function which converted a `Colour` to a `String`, or a `Colour` to anything else, and have searched the documents on Hackage for the Gtk package, but did not find anything there that would do what I wanted. I have also searched the internet, and could not find much about dealing with the `Colour` type. I did find one function for doing exactly what I wanted, located at the bottom [here](http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/apelsin/tree/src/Preferences.hs?id=4f8dec8a2b146e575edce8836bc286bc6794caf6).  However, this had the same problem, in that it wouldn't give the same value as the colour picker itself gave for a particular selection.

#### Update 1

I have also tried bitshifting the values. Shifting by 8 bits almost always gives the right value, but, as per the other things I tried, every so often it is slightly out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer to my own question here - after a bit of digging, I've found that what I want to do is convert what the GTK colour picker gave me - that is, a 16 bits-per-channel colour - into an 8 bpc colour. Armed with that, I found [this](https://forums.adobe.com/message/2596072) page on the Adobe forums. Using the answer posted there, I wrote some Haskell code which will convert a value of type `Color` into a Hex triplet, and seems, as far as I've found, to always match up with the value reported on the colour picker itself. Here's the code I'm using:

```
toHex :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> String
toHex i
  | length o == 1 = '0':o
  | otherwise     = o
  where
    o = map toUpper $ showHex i ""

d16to8 :: Integral a => a -> Integer
d16to8 i = (255 * d16to15 + 16385) `div` 32768
  where d16to15 =  (32768 * (toInteger i) + 32768) `div` 65535

colorToHex :: Color -> String
colorToHex (Color a b c) = (toHex.d16to8 $ a) ++ (toHex.d16to8 $ b) ++ (toHex.d16to8 $ c)
```